# Trying to setUser for google calendar by getting url from databse

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, session, google-calendar-api

the code below shows the link to my google calendar:

```
        $query = $gcal->newEventQuery();
        $query->setUser('*********c@group.calendar.google.com');
        $query->setVisibility('private');
        $query->setProjection('basic');
```

However i was trying to setUser by getting the calendar url from my database, due to wanting sessions to show paticular calendar for a user, using the code below:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION["SESS_CALENDAR"]))
    $val = $_SESSION["SESS_CALENDAR"];
    else
    $val = "";
```

and then inserting the $val into:

```
    $query->setUser($val);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question? You have described what you are doing, but don't say what, if anything, is going wrong. What should be happening and what is happening? You won't get an answer without asking a question first!

Answer (score 0):

I tryed it again from scratch it works fine, the only thing that i changed was when adding the new column into mySQL database was to include NOT NULL.